Issue with font-display on website using woff2 format
Somehow the custom font I embedded on my website is displayed in a weird way, for example on Firefox 115:

Do you know why that is? Maybe I need to use another converter / format? I used transfonter for conversion and embedded the fonts like this:
@font-face {
        font-family: "InterTight";
        font-weight: 400;
        src: url("../fonts/inter-tight-v7-latin-regular.woff2") format("woff2");
    }

    @font-face {
        font-family: "InterTight";
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: italic;
        src: url("../fonts/inter-tight-v7-latin-italic.woff2") format("woff2");
    }

    @font-face {
        font-family: "InterTight";
        font-weight: 500;
        src: url("../fonts/inter-tight-v7-latin-500.woff2") format("woff2");
    }

    @font-face {
        font-family: "InterTight";
        font-weight: 600;
        src: url("../fonts/inter-tight-v7-latin-600.woff2") format("woff2");
    }


We can't really debug this, without having your actual font file. If you suspect the used generator tool to be at fault here, maybe try https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator instead.
